# Trigger Jquery after form submission

Tags: 8, forms, javascript

I'm trying to trigger a javascript function after specific types of form submission on my site, as I want it to do something with the submitted data. I'm much more familiar with D7 than I am D8, and hence less familiar with the way D8 is object oriented so I'm just trying to check I'm going about it the right way.

In my module file

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments().
 */
function mymodule_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {   
    $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/mymodule';
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'comment_comment_form':
            $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_form_submission';
        break;
            
        default: 
            break;
    }
}

function mymodule_form_submission(array $form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state){
    $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();
    $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'myTest', ['test']));
    return $ajax_response;
}
```

In the libraries.yml file

```
mymodule:
  version: 1.x
  header: true
  js:
    js/bootstrap.js: {}
    js/actions.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/drupal
    - core/drupalSettings
```

In my actions.js file

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
    Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
        attach(context, settings) {
            $.fn.myTest = function (data) {
                console.log('My Test Has called');
                alert(data);
            };
        }
    };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```

I've modified the code to make it more readable on here, but I've gone through and tested each part, eg, my library is being added to the page, I've tested it being there by just writing to the console, I've tested the form_alter is being run and adding my extra submission action to the page by doing kint() or dpm() for the values, which also works, but at the moment I just don't seem to be able to trigger the AJAX Response to do my javascript command

I've been following [this example](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-pass-webform-submission-data-to-javascript) on how to pass webform data to javascript, but in that code it seems to enforce ajax submission of the form (which I don't *necessarily* want to do, unless it's the only way this will work)

Basically, I'm just trying to take the data within the form submissions and trigger a javascript command, is this the right way to do it?

Comment: `unless it's the only way this will work` Is is because the page will get refreshed and you'll lose all the JS files that were loaded. JS files will get reloaded/reset/restarted and if they were still processing you'll lose the progress.

Comment: @NoSssweat, is there any way of queueing that action then? Like if it could be put into something to be then executed on cron or something? Just because my plan was also to use this on the login/registration form, which I'm guessing cannot be AJAX enabled

Comment: Cron only works server side, which means your JS code, client side, cannot be ran on cron. What exactly is the purpose of your JS code anyways? What exactly do you want to do? Perhaps that can be accomplished with PHP instead?

Comment: @NoSssweat it's for user activity tracking, we're trying to implement a module that sends user registrations/logins to our analytics platform, but we have to send those commands via javascript

Comment: Which analytics platform are you using?

Comment: @NoSssweat it's called Discovr analytics

Comment: Errr.. they don't post their API publicly. You sure that JS file can't be converted to PHP? . They may not have a PHP snipped for you, but you could convert it to PHP yourself.

Comment: @NoSssweat I can ask their dev, I'm in direct communication with him. I'm 99% certain that some of the code has to be done in javascript as its reacting to page activity, but not these things I guess

Comment: Otherwise, the only workaround solution is see is to create a fake button that triggers the JS and then once the JS has done its thing, it auto clicks the real submit button for them, which would be hidden from display via JS.

Comment: Actually you don't even need a fake button, do `event.preventDefault();` run other JS code, then [Reenable event.preventDefault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164132/how-to-reenable-event-preventdefault) and perhaps you'll need to auto click the button for them again.

Comment: I've spoken to the dev and the platform his system is built on has a PHP api, so I'm checking into that, but thanks for your help with this so far